# Reduce the use of DigitalWrite()

Tags: arduino-uno, arduino-c++

I'm currently doing a circuit which has two seven segment display. Is there any codes to lessen the usage of digitalwrite()? `your text`

I also found some codes in arduino for a single seven segment to reduce the digitalwrite.

Here is my code

```
int E1 = 13;
int E2 = 12;
int D1 = 11;
int D2 = 10;
int C1 = 9;
int C2 = 8;
int G1 = 7;
int G2 = 6;
int F1 = 5;
int F2 = 4;
int a1 = 3;
int a2 = 2;
int b1 = 1;
int B2 = 0;
  
//setting up the pin
void setup()
{
  pinMode(E1, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(E2, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(D1, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(D2, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(C1, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(C2, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(G1, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(G2, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(F1, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(F2, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(a1, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(a2, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(b1, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(B2, OUTPUT);
}

byte pinNumArr [7]{A1, B1, C1, D1, E1, F1,G1};
byte number7S [10] [7] = 
{
    {HIGH,HIGH,HIGH,HIGH,HIGH,HIGH, LOW}, // Number 0
    {LOW,HIGH,HIGH,LOW,LOW,LOW, LOW},  // Number 1
    {HIGH,HIGH,LOW,HIGH,HIGH,LOW,HIGH},  // Number 2
    {HIGH,HIGH,HIGH,HIGH,LOW,LOW,HIGH},  // Number 3
    {LOW,HIGH,HIGH,LOW,LOW,HIGH,HIGH},  // Number 4
    {HIGH,LOW,HIGH,HIGH,LOW,HIGH,HIGH},  // Number 5
    {HIGH,LOW,HIGH,HIGH,HIGH,HIGH,HIGH},  // Number 6
    {HIGH,HIGH,HIGH,LOW,LOW,LOW,LOW},  // Number 7
    {HIGH,HIGH,HIGH,HIGH,HIGH,HIGH,HIGH},  // Number 8
    {LOW,HIGH,HIGH,HIGH,LOW,HIGH,HIGH}  // Number 9

};

void displayNumber(byte value = 0 )
{
   for (int idx = 0; idx < 7; idx++)
   {
     digitalWrite(pinNumArr[idx], number7S[value][idx]);
     value = number7S[value][idx];
   }
 };

void loop()
{
    displayNumber();
     delay(500);
}
```

I want to lessen the usage of digitalwrite for double seven segment display

Answer (score 1):

You can do direct port manipulation instead of all those digitalWrite().

Digital pins 0-7 are on PORTD and digital pins 8-13 are on PORTB.

You can set all of the pins in one line like this:

```
PORTB = B00000000; //Set pin 8-13 LOW
```

or you could say:

```
PORTB = B00010100; //Set pin 10 and 12 HIGH, all others low
```